# Installing USB to ATA/Atapi bridge driver

Tags: usb, drivers, bridge, ata, atapi

I am using Windows XP **64 bit** version on Lenovo W520. I am trying to install my devices, I plugged a USB cable that is linked to a SATA interface (to copy from old sata HDD) and when I plug the USB cable it tries to install this device:

USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge driver

Is there anywhere I can get this driver? I see Microsoft has some fixes for this but for Win 7 and Vista.

It appears to me it is a generic driver and not directly related to this Sata to usb interface. On windows XP 32 bit and windows 7 it worked by default.

Also, it might be related: my card reader doesn't show as a drive letter, but it does make the device on/off sound when I plug a card in. I see the card reader in my device manager.

Comment: If you can see the drive in Disk Management, mount it from there.  See if that takes care of the issue.

Comment: Thanks @BonGart Works for me on Windows 10